# Trying to match an AspectJ pointcut signature for any methods containing a variable

Tags: java, spring-mvc, aspectj, pointcuts

I want to create a pointcut that matches *any* method in my Web controller that contains a ModelMap:

```
pointcut addMenu(ModelMap modelMap) : 
    execution (public String example.web.MyController.*(..)) && args (modelMap);

before(ModelMap modelMap) : addMenu(modelMap) {
    // Do stuff with modelMap...
}
```

My problem is that this only matches methods with **ONLY** the ModelMap parameter, others are not matched because they contain too many parameters. For example, this is not intercepted, due to the "req" parameter:

```
public String request(HttpServletRequest req, ModelMap modelMap) {
    // Handle request
}
```

Is there any way to match all methods with a ModelMap parameter, without having to add a pointcut delegate for every possible parameter combination?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use wildcards `*` or `..` to express the arguments in a flexible way.

```
pointcut addMenu(ModelMap modelMap) : 
    execution (public String example.web.MyController.*(..)) && args (*, modelMap);
```

See [AspectJ: parameter in a pointcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265680/aspectj-parameter-in-a-pointcut)

Comment: Thanks. That comes close to what I want, but it causes the pointcut to no longer match my "request(ModelMap modelMap)" methods, because it is expecting more than one argument.

Comment: Yes, that the problem related in the linked post in my answer. Either try with ".." or make two pointcuts "*, modelMap" and "modelMap".